# What kinds of Open-Source licenses are NOT OK to use internally in a corporation?

Tags: licensing, open-source

I have recently learned about several cool open source add-on tools and libraries for Microsoft Visual Studio. The tools just help you be more productive; the libraries would get linked into the corporate code base.

I have listed all these cool tools and libraries on a spreadsheet and I'm going to run down the type of license each one is under. So far, amongst my cool libraries, I see **MIT**, **BSD**, **Apache License Version 2.0**. However, there could be more in the future.

How can I find out (or better yet, can you just list) the popular licenses which are NOT compatible with internal corporate use (not to be distributed outside the company)? And for an extra thank you, can you say or point to an explanation. I'm not a lawyer and reading the fine print of these licenses gives me a headache.

I want to be prepared to explain why using the allowable licenses is OK.

Comment: You would really want to take this up with someone from your company.  As a general principle, using anything GPL in proprietary software is a violation.  The GPL license is *viral*, which means if your company uses GPL-licensed code, they essentially have to open-source *the entire project.*  Most open-source licenses are not viral, though.  Some, like the Mozilla Public License, require you to freely publish changes you make *to the MPL codebase itself*, but that requirement doesn't carry over to your own code.  But this is really too broad of a question to easily answer here.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Provisions like copyleft are *all about distribution;* if the program is only ever going to be used internally, *it doesn't matter.*

Comment: @toddmo: seems Mason Wheeler when writing about GPL ignored completely the part "not to be distributed outside the company" of your question? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492687/using-gpl-3rd-party-code-for-internal-closed-source-project

Comment: Useful reading: http://lwn.net/Articles/635290/

Comment: Even Richard Stallman himself says all the time that if you use GPL software and don't distribute it, you don't have to contribute anything. But always read the license. Especially the shorter licenses are not THAT hard to read. If you can read computer code, come on, you can read these licenses.

Comment: @Brandin, what specifically do you mean by "contribute" (pay, improve the code, post boilerplate)? Anyway, the problem is that any "common sense" I think I have when it comes to interpreting "terms" goes out the window in a legal arena where "common sense" as we know it is set aside completely and is replaced by whatever lawyers abide by (I've been in divorce court; trust me, I know). Using any kind of license, short / long, without first consulting war veterans who may have learned the hard way (or just through being smart), would be a reckless thing for me to do.

Comment: @Brandin, also see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492687/using-gpl-3rd-party-code-for-internal-closed-source-project), which goes into how a GPL can be problematic even internally (now I sound like a lawyer lol). Not to mention the scenario where internal becomes external. I know, I so wish GPL and actually *anything* was OK. Taint so. :(

Comment: Famous example, countless companies use Linux internally (which is GPL) and they have no problems. So I don't really get where the perceived risk is coming from.

Comment: @Brandin, well, a few folks here seem to think it's a problem, but if I find a cool library that is GPL, I can use Linux to argue to be able to use it. So, thanks :)

Comment: @Brandin I think you are conflating "use" with "modify".  Most companies use Linux as an OS as-is.  In this case, there is nothing for them to distribute.  The more complex case is a tool that is used internally.  In theory, a company could take Linux source, and modify it without ever make the modification public *if* they never made this resulting Linux distribution public.  But that is extremely rare, if it has ever happened at all.

Comment: @toddmo The answers on that question point out that the GPL for internal-only software *isn't* a problem. As long as you do not intentionally release a GPLed thing outside your company, you have no obligations to share the source with anyone (not even your employees; you can give it to just developers if you'd like). The [GPL FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#InternalDistribution) is explicit on this point.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I just don't see how using Linux as an OS "as-is" is any different from any other developer tool. Point is, if GPL were truly "viral" then you couldn't even instal Linux onto your server let alone your workstation because its GPL-ness might infect your office and then the GPL police would come in and say "where is the source???"

Comment: @cpast, you are absolutely correct in what you say. But what I've learned from this question is that if what is internal today ever becomes external, then you run into a problem, right? So I need to at least be aware of that and think about the odds of that happening. At best I could have a contingency plan to replace that library with a commercial product in that event. I guess that would depend on the company and the app (is it potentially sellable). Business folks, like lawyers, can occasionally shock me with how different their thought process is from mine.

Comment: @Brandin, I think we're only talking about libraries here, not tools. Maybe that will help reconcile the discussion. Tools aren't going to be distributed. I'm willing to make that assumption.

Comment: @toddmo If you use the library internally then it is the same as using any other tool internally. However, quite often you link a library with your own code to make your product. But if you distribute your product with someone else's library linked in, it's kind of like copying out a chapter from someone else's book and placing it into your own book which you are selling. To do this you need permission (i.e. a license) from the author. OTOH, if you just keep a copy of that chapter sitting on your desk for reference, then that's no problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe that using GPL free software is not ok. You should read the [GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html)

Comment: A big lot of corporations (e.g.Google, Airbus, ....) are using GPL free software; they just have lawyers understanding the licenses.

Comment: Some companies do sell products with GPL code. They just obey to the requirement to publish that GPL code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22402/discussion-between-basile-starynkevitch-and-toddmo).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, because of Robert's answer, the viral portion of GPL, if the company decides to distribute it. I'd rather err on the side of caution. Thanks.

Comment: IF yoiu are a developer (like I am) you are not a laywer (and IANAL neither). So ask your lawyer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I got my answer, and I'm happy with it, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal topics (and while questions about software licenses *in concrete source code* could be borderline here), legal questions outside of some specific software are for lawyers (and depends upon the legal system: I'm French, not USAian) so are off-topic here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Questions about licenses from the perspective of a software developer (Eg. usage, which license, understanding, etc..) are ON topic, as long as they are not asking for special legal advice.  My impression is that this question is ok as the OP is looking for guidance on selecting an appropriate license for software that he is working on.

Comment: I think that questions about your company's policies are best directed toward management and legal department. We don't know what your company is willing to do, and being OK may be different. There's also a difference between using a tool, using the output of a tool, modifying a tool's source, and distributing the tool. At the end of the day, there's just way too many factors for this to be a reasonable question for the Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general, the legalities in licensing that can occur as a result of the use of open-source software boil down to two factors:

1. Commercial use, and
2. Distribution.

Distribution means "conferring" software to a third party outside the organization.  Since you say you only use the software internally, legal mechanisms like "copyleft" (the term used for the viral portion of the GPL license) probably don't apply to your organization.

Commercial use (or other arbitrary restrictions) are a different matter.  Simply read the license carefully, and determine if any of those restrictions apply to your organization.  In particular, permissive licenses such as Apache, MIT and BSD have few, if any, restrictive conditions; these licenses are ideal for "internal use."

It sounds like your company is reluctant to use open-source software.  Many companies believe that they must completely own their software and other intellectual property, and so they have policies that state that their own developers must write every line of code.  Clarifying the meaning of open-source licenses will not necessarily change their minds.

Comment: I only found 3 distinct licenses among my libraries (see edit). Any specific thoughts about those? And then I'll mark as answer. Thanks Robert!

Comment: None of those three licenses have any specific restrictions that would prevent your company from using them freely in a company-internal context.  They are all considered "permissive" licenses.

Comment: Just be very careful about the meaning of the word "internal". Older open-source licenses, such as the original GPL, had loopholes that permitted its use as a "back-end" library or product. You could use a GPL database product to hold the content for a commercial web site. Newer licenses, such as the AGPL, are essentially "viral" - they apply to the entire network, and if you have a user-facing/commercial product that *talks to* some internal product using AGPL software, even in a trivial fashion, you would technically be in violation of the license unless you release **all** your source code.

Comment: Most companies simply won't touch "copyleft" licenses, and for good reason; it's borderline impossible to perfectly "quarantine" a system and ensure that nothing ever indirectly touches the GPL/AGPLed code. Some apparently "permissive" licenses like WTFPL are no help either, because they're too vague on important legal issues like copyright. Even if you think you could successfully defend against a lawsuit, do you really want to go through that? (Hint: Your lawyercats probably don't.) Stick to Apache and MIT. I think BSD is also OK.

Comment: @Aaronaught Do you have any generally respected source that supports your claim that the WTFPL is vague wrt copyright? The FSF accepts it as GPL-compatible. The major Linux distributions accept it as free. I can find a claim that the OSI rejected it as too vague, but this is false, the OSI rejected it as redundant, as a quick Google search for "wtfpl osi" will confirm. I can think of issues with the WTFPL, sure, but when it comes to copyrights, vagueness is not one of those issues.

Comment: @Bob Read on, the final rejection reason was that it was redundant since the Fair License already existed. :)

Comment: @hvd: You're citing a bunch of open-source software foundations as evidence here. My whole point is that these license agreements are generally fine **for open-source software**, but have a lot of problems when it comes to commercial purposes, even if the software is only "internal". One of the major issues with WTFPL is that it doesn't have a "no warranties" clause. To that, the authors respond "add your own", which doesn't address the issue at all. My source is actual corporate lawyers, both full-time and consultant. I neither need nor am inclined to search for an internet source.

Comment: @Aaronaught Vagueness is actually one thing that neither the FSF nor the major Linux distributions accept. If a license is vague, then it will be neither classified as free nor as unfree. Example: the original Artistic License. Anyway, the warranty issue is one I could think of, but that's unrelated to copyright. You claimed "they're too vague on important legal issues like copyright", and I specifically asked you to clarify how it's vague wrt copyright. Another issue is that it's unclear whether it applies to any trademarks and/or patents. That's also a separate issue from copyright.

Comment: @hvd: It may shock you to know that corporate lawyers don't really care about things like "free" or "unfree". They care about "can we use this without getting sued?". Have you actually **read** [the WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/)? It tells you nothing. Read section 2 of the [Apache License](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) to see what a proper copyright clause looks like. The WTFPL neither explicitly grants a copyright license, nor does it make said license irrevocable. You don't need to read the FSF's evaluation - just look at the license yourself!

Comment: We're still talking about this?

Comment: @Aaronaught The FSF cares about clarity just like corporate lawyers do. Just because they also care about other things doesn't mean they ignore clarity. Yes, I have read the WTFPL, and you should already know I did. How else could I have formed any objections to it? As for the license possibly being revocable, that's a fair point that's not at all specific to that particular license. A lot of licenses don't cover it. It's probably not necessary, see [this](http://www.advogato.org/article/606.html) for instance, but I can certainly agree that the license would be clearer if it made it explicit.

Comment: @Aaronaught AGPL doesn't really seem that popular. Can you name any major AGPL software? On the other hand, for all the other licenses like GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPL, Apache, MIT, BSD, MPL, its easy to pick many major projects in each license.

Comment: @Aaronaught WTFPL explicitly lets you relicense the software under another license of your choice (e.g. Apache License). WTFPL authors obviously made the "license" because they want to place some software in public domain, but they can't due to many jurisdictions not recognizing the concept.

Comment: @Brandin: GPLv2 and GPLv3 have the same issues as AGPL. LGPL is often OK, depending on what kind of product you work on. Apache, MIT, and BSD are permissive. I don't think anyone other than Mozilla uses MPL. WTFPL doesn't *explicitly* let you do anything, relicensing is just one possible interpretation of the license. Believe me or don't, I don't care; I'm telling you how it is, most lawyers will tell you not to touch GPL and its offshoots with a 10-foot pole if you plan on doing any kind of commerce, related or not. Those licenses are specifically meant to "spread" open-source.

Comment: BTW, [RedHat](http://www.redhat.com/), [AdaCore](http://www.adacore.com/), [Intel](http://www.intel.com/), [AMD](http://amd.com/) are not only using but are *actively contributing* to GPL software.

Comment: A license that explicitly forbids use commercial use would not meet the OSI definition of Open Source (6. No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor) nor the FSF definition of Free Software (The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom 0). | Though it's still allowed to add requirements like Copy-Left which effectively prevent their use in many commercial scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

There are some things to be aware off: First, your company lawyers may get a fit if you use third party code without asking them. So you shouldn't use any third party code without telling your boss or manager and getting their consent. As you said, you are not a lawyer.

Second, a nasty one: If you find code on the internet, and it has some license, you don't know where it comes from. You don't know if the person who added the license actually had the right to do so.

Third, for GPL license and internal use: Things that are for internal use today may not stay for internal use. You might have written some really nice software for internal use, and your company might decide to make some money off it by selling it. And then you might have a problem.

Comment: In your second example, that would be someone else's problem

Comment: @whatsisname Tell that to the original author when she sues you.

Comment: @whatsisname If A wrote the software and holds the copyrights, B distributes it under some license without permission, and C get the software from B and uses and perhaps modifies or redistributes it, then if A catches C doing so, A has no obligation, moral or legal, to go after B. A may not even be aware of B. C is the one caught using, modifying, redistributing, so C is the one who has to stop and pay damages. There is no way in hell that C will be allowed to continue. At best, C can then go after B in court, but that's only if C can actually find B. Good luck if it's some guy in e.g. China.

Comment: The situation in paragraph 2 is always a possiblity. Suppose you purchase a commercial source library with the license to use that closed source linked in your code.   How do you really know that the company that sold you that software legally has a right to it?

Comment: Paragraph two is the most dangerous.  I personally ran into this myself when a developer mention that a bit of code was "something he found on some site somewhere" fairly close to release.  Not fun.  Lesson #412 in "why you should code review everything".

Comment: @sapi, whoops, meant to say the third example.

Comment: @Brandin This is why one of the most important parts of "can I use this without being sued" is having the company you get the software from sign something either (preferably) expressly stating that they have the right to sell you the software, or (less preferably) implying it and at least giving you someone to sue if needed. You can go after whoever sold you the software if they lied and made you believe they could sell it to you; played right, C ends up with no net payment to A (B pays C the balance of what C paid A). It's just that it's company C's job to go after them, not company A's.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on context.

If you want to use any open source software you are free to.

If you want to use any open source software for the basis of internal company projects then you are also free to ( since the more contagious licences like the gpl require you to provide the source code upon request to all who the compiled code is distributed to, if it's a internal application then this is a non issue )

If you want to used open source software for the basis of a product then you have to follow the licence carefully ( get your company lawyers involved for this ) and if the licence is infectious then you may have to make your source code available to all those who receive the compiled code . In some cases this is acceptable ( for example writing a custom product for a single customer who owns the source code anyway ) in others this is not ( for example a product which is sold to the general public with a "trial" version available for anyone )

But to answer your question directly lgpl and gpl are perfectly fine for internal corporate use.

Since I can download nedit, or gnu, change it to my hearts content without the need to make my code public, and then use it myself there is no difference to me doing so for my employers own internal use.